# TypeDoc crashes right after start

Tags: typescript, typedoc

I run the command:

> typedoc --out ./typeDocDocs ./src

It starts then shows an error which says nothing for me:

```
Using TypeScript 3.2.4 from MY_PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\typescript\lib
MY_PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\typedoc\dist\lib\converter\context.js:194
    return node['name'] && (ts.isIdentifierOrPrivateIdentifier(node['name']) ||
                               ^

TypeError: ts.isIdentifierOrPrivateIdentifier is not a function
at isNamedNode (MY_PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\typedoc\dist\lib\converter\context.js:194:32)
at Context.getSymbolAtLocation (MY_PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\typedoc\dist\lib\converter\context.js:47:24)
at Object.createDeclaration (MY_PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\typedoc\dist\lib\converter\factories\declaration.js:61:32)
at ClassConverter.convert (MY_PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\typedoc\dist\lib\converter\nodes\class.js:28:34)
at Converter.convertNode (MY_PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\typedoc\dist\lib\converter\converter.js:116:53)
at MY_PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\typedoc\dist\lib\converter\nodes\block.js:58:32
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at BlockConverter.convertStatements (MY_PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\typedoc\dist\lib\converter\nodes\block.js:56:29)
at MY_PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\typedoc\dist\lib\converter\nodes\block.js:43:26
at Context.withScope (MY_PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\typedoc\dist\lib\converter\context.js:108:9)
```

TypeDoc version 0.17.1

Can anybody help me to run TypeDoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like an [incompatibility with TypeScript version](https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc/issues/1240) that was introduced in the last month.

I just isolated the issue to v0.17.0, so if you run an [older version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typedoc?activeTab=versions) you should be able to get it working. Mine worked with `npm i -D typedoc@0.16.11`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I downgraded to v0.16.9 and it works now. Thought, the compodoc looks like the better choice.